# How do I configure dart2js options from Dart Editor?

Tags: dart, dart-editor

I use Dart Editor to launch my app into Chrome or Firefox. I'd like to control the command-line options that are passed to dart2js by Dart Editor. For example, I want to minify the code. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Click the little drop-down arrow to the right of the green Run icon:

[image]

Then select "Manage Launches".

Then, find your *run config* for your app.

[image]

Add `--minify` to the "Compiler flags".

To find a list of available flags, run `dart2js --help` from the command line (assuming the Dart SDK is on your path).

Comment: Although it's mentioned in output of `dart2js --help`, would be nice to highlight that `dart2js --help -v` shows *all* possible options.

Comment: Hey Seth, the latest Dart Editor (version 0.8.5_r28990) does not have this dart2js settings.

Comment: This option is gone from the Dart Editor 1.2.  Any pointers where to find it now?